# Exception: The starting row of the range is too small - Logs Numbers Why?

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, range

I have a basic script to take numbers from a sheet and use them to create a range, as well as using the last column function.  I have had the error range is too small for the posting range.

When I log the output for both the column and row numbers these come out as expected!

I thought initially, it was because one was a last column pull and the other was pulling an integer from the cell in the sheets, as they were coming with decimal places, so I have overcome this with the conversion to number and then removing the decimals with the .tofixed() but this does not work either.  Any ideas?

```
 function weeklyData() {
  var sourcess = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1B93Oq2s9Nou5hVgOb3y3t15t9xnqRMBnrYkAed-oxrE');  // key of source spreadsheet
  var sourceSheet = sourcess.getSheetByName('Measures & Answers');  // source sheet name - change to your actual sheet name
  var lr = Number(sourceSheet.getRange(2,3).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow()).toFixed(0);

for(var i=0;i<lr+1;i++){ 
  var dataValue = sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,3).getValue(); //This weeks numbers to update into table

  var rowdataRange = sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,4).getValue(); //The row that the data needs to be pasted
  var rowformat = Number(rowdataRange);
  var row = rowformat.toFixed(0);

  var pasteSheet = sourcess.getSheetByName('WHERE DATA ENDS UP');  // Data is to be pasted - change to your actual sheet name
  var pasteColumn = pasteSheet.getRange(12,12).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS).getLastColumn()+1;
  var column = pasteColumn.toFixed(0); // Column that is free for this weeks data

  var pasteRange = pasteSheet.getRange(row,column,1,1);

 Logger.log(pasteRange);

//  pasteRange.setValue(dataValue);

  }};
```

Comment: Hello @TORJL, would you mind sharing a sanitized copy of your sheet as well? Moreover, at which line do you get the above message? Cheers!

Comment: I am having problems with line 17 of the script.  The sheet is: 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B93Oq2s9Nou5hVgOb3y3t15t9xnqRMBnrYkAed-oxrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think it is the loop getting to the end.  The numbers are posting into the right sheet, but I am still getting the error at the end of the loop.  How can I resolve this, as I am passing the code on to someone else?

Comment: Hello @TORJL, please make the sheet shareable! Cheers :)

Comment: Published now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS4VyFSBknoktMzuAmM5n8WS_gxmZKMPQ4tmX6pRu-VB3uLksPhL7T486tDugBj-X5SMdaAEFP-1Ndh/pubhtml

Comment: Hello @TORJL, you need to edit the sharing permissions. I am still not able to access your Sheet. Cheers!

Comment: Try this one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B93Oq2s9Nou5hVgOb3y3t15t9xnqRMBnrYkAed-oxrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @TORJL, the link you shared is still not accessible. Go to *Share* -> Set the permissions - the preferable one in this case is "On - anyone with the link can view" -> *Get sharable link*. Cheers!

Comment: I have had set it up with my personal Google Account... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10l7ETUOC2whZofNelrQSa8Xu4BFZT--8cnVQs7OonuE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @TORJL, I got the spreadsheet. Now can you please tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to copy the values from the 3rd and 4th column and past them into the next available slots in the other sheet? Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to take the values from the 3rd column and paste them into the next available column on the main sheet, at the row number entered in the 4th column.  It works,  but then I get an error at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check your Spreadsheet since it has lots of random values at random ranges.

When you use the following command `Logger.log(pasteSheet.getLastColumn());` the number returned is **`3753`**: which means that that is the next available column at which your data will be pasted.

The error message you were getting is due to the fact that the range was incorrect and you were passing wrong values in order to access it, which was most likely because of the values mentioned above.

Moreover, after cleaning all the unnecessary data, you can make use of the below script.

#### Snippet

```
function weeklyData() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET");
    var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Measures & Answers");
    var pasteSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("WHERE DATA ENDS UP");

    var valsToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    var rowsAt = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 4, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    var column = pasteSheet.getRange(12,12).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS).getLastColumn()+1;  

    for (var i = 0; i < valsToCopy.length; i++) 
        if (rowsAt[i][0] != "") 
            pasteSheet.getRange(parseInt(rowsAt[i][0]), parseInt(column)).setValue(valsToCopy[i][0].toString());

}
```

#### Explanation

The above script gathers all the data that needs to be copied as well as the rows associated with it. In order to make sure you don't end up using inappropriate values for the ranges, an `if` condition has been placed to make sure the value is not `empty`.

#### Reference

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn);
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns);

Comment: THANK YOU!  I have had to tweak it slightly, as the columns were out of sync with being the next available on, so I have added a line before the loop to find the last available column and used the same format for parseInt for the column number and it works a treat without any errors.   var column = pasteSheet.getRange(12,12).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS).getLastColumn()+1;
    for (var i = 0; i < valsToCopy.length; i++) {
        if (rowsAt[i][0] != "") {
    
            pasteSheet.getRange(parseInt(rowsAt[i][0]), parseInt(column)).setValue(valsToCopy[i][0].toString());

Comment: Hello @TORJL, I edited my post to your particular situation. I am glad your situation has been resolved! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your script works fine for me. I suspect this is an example script you've adapted from somewhere and trying to apply it to your data structure?

The reason you are getting the error is probably because the data in column 4 of your source sheet is not of number format? Either change your data or change the following line to the column containing numeric values.

```
var rowdataRange = sourceSheet.getRange(i+2,4).getValue();
```

This script is poorly written for this particular use.